# MVC : How does it work a ajax call to controller action passing less parameters than what is required but it still works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have this function on my view page

```
var params = {
                Param1: $('#as').val(),
                Param2: $('input[name=dswe]').val(),
                Param3: $('inpu`enter code here`t:radio[name=wer]:checked').val()
            }
  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'controlleractionname',
                    data: params,
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.statusText);
                    },

                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#Message').html('MRR Received Date SAVED');
                        closeDialog();

                    },
                    cache: false
                });
```

This calls the following action on controller page

```
  public string controlleractionname(string param1, DateTime param2, int param3, Classdata data1)
        {

     code is here
        }
```

Now, my question is this works perfectly fine, but I wanted to know how is this working ? since I am passing only 3 parameters from ajax to this controller action. The fourth parameter is a datacontract class of a WCF service.

I am asking because this is a working application and I am new to this project and trying to understand the functionality.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: When you are calliing an action you do not have to supply all parameters

Comment: I'm curious; why do C# (or some other .NET flavor, not sure actually) questions about the MVC architecture so often only mention the `mvc` tag, as if C# has the monopoly on `mvc`? In other words: please add a proper language tag to go with it as well. (I'm not sure whether this is actually C#, otherwise I would have added the proper tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ASP.NET MVC receives a request first it matches it to a route. You must have a route that matches the URL that you are posting to.

Once ASP.NET MVC has found a match it will instantiate the controller that was indicated in the route and call the action method also indicated on the route.

At this point ASP.NET MVC goes through a process where it tries to find information from the HTTP request (form values, query string parameters, et cetera) and matches it to the parameters defined in your method definition for the action. For example, if MVC finds a query string parameter "param1" it will automatically pass the query string value to the "param1" in your method. If it cannot find a value in the request it will pass a default value (e.g. null for strings, 0 for integers.)

This is a simplified explanation but I hope it gives you an idea of what's going on.